# TC- HFSC : Can we have TC rule to set classes with minimum guarantee, but no maximum limit?

Tags: traffic, tc

Can we set a rule where i can specify that my particular traffic will get minimum b/w no matter what, but no max limit if bandwidth is available.

Eg : I have 20 mbps line.
i want to set minimum 5 mbps for my voip traffic.
so in case no one is using any bandwidth voip traffic should be able to utilize the 20 mbps else it will get minimum 5mbps.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `ls` parameter at 5Mb without `ul`, it will do what you want. 
If you want to hard cap at 5Mb, you'll need to add `ul` at 5Mb.
If multiple class are competing for the same additional bandwidth, they will get it proportionally to their ls parameter. (so the ls 10Mb will have twice more additional bandwidth than the ls 5Mb one)